# firebase realtime database calling set with new properties

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

i am using firebase realtime DB with my ionic app and using angularfire2. I have data stored like:

```
"users" : {
    "230A3lKQqWh0TczOGP8sbtMVpuF2" : {
      "email" : "xxx@gmail.com",
      "isAdmin" : false,
      "name" : "Santosh Yadav",
      "pic" : "https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/picture"
    },
    "oSEYj0zrkhPCk9r7uwyOOkHcqe53" : {
      "email" : "yyy@gmail.com",
      "isAdmin" : true,
      "name" : "Vik Kumar",
      "pic" : "https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/picture"
    },
    "tl3uvseaBeWVYFCTwSngUqcSokX2" : {
      "email" : "zzz@gmail.com",
      "isAdmin" : false,
      "name" : "Neeti Singhal",
      "pic" : "https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/picture"
    }
}
```

We ended up to store more user data like date of birth and date of aniversary and when we try to update it as below:

```
createUser(user:User){
    console.log('start of create user')
    var payload = {
      "name": user.name,
      "email": user.email,
      "pic" : user.pic,
      "dob" : user.dob,
      "anivDate" : user.anivDate,
    }

    return this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).set(payload).then(
      (resp) => console.log("user created")
    ).catch(
      (err) => console.log("issues creating user:" + err)
    )
  }
```

It fails with error:

```
ERROR Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.oSEYj0zrkhPCk9r7uwyOOkHcqe53.anivDate'
    at validateFirebaseData (validation.js:113)
    at validation.js:140
    at forEach (obj.js:46)
```

I understand the error that it is unable to set a property anivDate that does not exist in my firebase realtime DB. This will fix if i manually add the property into the db manually. But that is not a practical fix. So, what is the solution here?

To define the fix:  i am expecting to add a new property if that does not exist else just update it.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The error message indicates that `user.anivDate` doesn't exist (that's what `undefined` means here). Is that a situation you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, use the `||` operator to set a default value on `undefined` elements. Usage:

```
var payload = {
  "anivDate": user.anivDate || "1970-01-01",
  ...
};
```

This sets `anivDate` to `user.anivDate` if it exists, `1970-01-01` if it does not. (This works, but in my opinion it is better practice to not have a `anivDate` property on a user if no such value exists, and check for that value's existence when accessing the data.)

For a more scalable/reliable fix, use [Firebase's realtime database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to add async validating or default values to your new columns.